# The CryptoObject in BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult is always null

Tags: java, android, android-biometric-prompt

I am using biometric authentication dialog but my cryptoObject is always null.
I have a fragment but I also tried directly from the activity.

Here is my code,

private Handler biometricPromptHandler = new Handler();

```
private Executor executor = command -> biometricPromptHandler.post(command);
private void showBiometricPrompt( String title, String description,
                                 BiometricsCompatCallback compatCallback) {

    BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo =
            new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setSubtitle(description)
                    .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                    .build();

    BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt((FragmentActivity) context,
            executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode,
                                          @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            compatCallback.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            Log.d("onAuthenticationError", ": ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
                @NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
            Log.d("result", ": "+(result.getCryptoObject()));
            BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject authenticatedCryptoObject =
                    result.getCryptoObject();
            Log.d("onAuthentionSucceeded", ": "+(authenticatedCryptoObject==null));
            if (authenticatedCryptoObject != null) {
                 cipher = authenticatedCryptoObject.getCipher();
                Log.d("onAuthentionSucceeded", ": ");
                compatCallback.onAuthenticationSuccessful(cipher);
            }else {
                Log.d("cipher", "onAuthenticationSucceeded: ");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            Log.d("onAuthenticationFailed", ": ");
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
            compatCallback.onAuthenticationFailed();
        }
    });


        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);



}
```

Anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a `CryptoObject` from `AuthenticationResult`, you must first pass in a `CryptoObject` when you call `authenticate()`, like so:

```
// this example uses a Cipher but your code can use signature or mac
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher))
```

If you don't pass a CryptoObject when you call `authenticate()` then the API doesn't have one to return to you.

Check out [this blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd).

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide a Cipher in the second parameter of the `authenticate` method or it will always return `null`.

Use

```
authenticate(PromptInfo info, CryptoObject crypto)
```

instead of

```
authenticate(PromptInfo info)
```

Take a look to [this](https://dev.to/ranilch/securing-data-with-biometricprompt-35mo) tutorial and the sample project in [this repository](https://github.com/stravag/android-sample-biometric-prompt). You can use something like this:

```
BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(getEncryptCipher(createKey()));
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, cryptoObject);
```

Using (depending on the ciphering you want):

```
private SecretKey createKey() throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    String algorithm = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES;
    String provider = "AndroidKeyStore";
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm, provider);
    KeyGenParameterSpec keyGenParameterSpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("MY_KEY", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
            .build();

    keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec);
    return keyGenerator.generateKey();
}

private Cipher getEncryptCipher(Key key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    String algorithm = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES;
    String blockMode = KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC;
    String padding = KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7;
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm+"/"+blockMode+"/"+padding);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return cipher;
}
```

Comment: I will test your solution and let you know.